# How can I edit routes like playframework1.x in playframework2.x?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In `playframework1.x`, I can edit my route like this:

```
/{controller}/{action}         {controller}.{action}
```

to match all the actions in my controllers.
We are going to work on playframework2.x these days,but in the document in their site,need to edit every routes?  What if I have many routes?It's so 
tired!

So,can I just edit routes like `playframework1.x`?
thanks every much.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use routing method, you must edit them.

example:

```
GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login()
POST    /submit                     controllers.Application.submit()
```

Comment: I know this,but I want to use like            *       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}